# Clicking the flag button twice on a post occludes the text box

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, flag-dialog

1. Click on the *flag* button
2. Click on *Requires Moderator attention*
3. Click on the *flag* button *again*
4. .
   [Profit! http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/97/bugbp.png](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/97/bugbp.png)

Comment: It's even funnier if you try to vote to close before clicking on flag.

Comment: Yup, duplicated here. I'd upvote but I'm out of votes.

Comment: @Josh: share the link.

Comment: @voy: I think he meant that he reproduced the behaviour.

Comment: @Jon: you are likely right ;) I'm too used to dupe being "dupes"

Comment: The new, larger flagging dialog covers up the flag link, making this too localized.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed now! When you click on the flag button *once again* the previous flag dialog will disappear and the new dialog will appear.

Answer (score 2):

We haven't *fixed* this, per se, but we shadow the box now so you can see what's going on.

Ask for two dialogs, you get two dialogs..

Comment: Cancel one dialog, you cancel them all...?